# Configuration editor in Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

On Windows 2008 R2 when opening a web.config file it started a program with an editing interface similar to Visual Studio. Much more limited in features, but same interface and text colors, etc.

Now I don't have Windows 2008 anymore, I'm using Windows 2012, but it opens web.config files in notepad. Do you know which program it was that was included in Windows 2008 and if it is available for Windows 2012?

Comment: Too localized. "What did I used to have installed on an old server?" is something I can't help him with.

Comment: You may have had [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=40777) installed with some other tool. This provides a language independent IDE with a Visual Studio flavour.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a bunch of 2k8 R2 servers and `*.config` is associated with `notepad.exe`. I don't think your experience was with OS tools. Perhaps you had an additional product installed - perhaps even a version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Probably, just wondering what product that could have been :) For sure wasn't Visual Studio.